# Would you enter or will you enter

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, will-would

Let's say I see a person standing infront of a room. I want to ask him if he will enter or not. What would be the correct sentence to use here?

> *Would you enter?*

Or

> *Will you enter?*

One more question is:

> *What would be the correct sentence to use here?*

Or

> *What will be the correct sentence to use here?*

Comment: Are you inviting him to enter the room, or asking his intention?

Comment: I'm asking his intention.

Comment: In real life you would probably ask "Are you going in?" (or "coming in" if you were about to enter the room yourself).

Comment: Suppose my friend tells me that he is going to propose a girl and as far as I know, she will reject his proposal. So what should I say ? " She would reject your proposal" or " She will reject your proposal" ? Which one to use and why?

Comment: If he's definitely going to propose **to** her, you would use _will_. If the situation is hypothetical, you might say "If you were to propose to her, I think she would reject you."

Comment: The "will" can be conditional:  "What will happen if I propose to her?"  "She will reject you."

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask him if he will enter or not.

That a factual question about the future

So you use "Will you enter".

If you want to ask him if he would enter or not. Using a conditional, with an implied condition you ask, "Would you enter".  That implies there is an unspoken "if ..."

For the other question, I'd use "What is the correct sentence", probably.  It depends on what you mean.

Comment: Ok I got it. What about the later ones ? "What would be the correct sentence to use here" or "What will be the correct sentence to use here" ?

Comment: I'd use "What is the correct sentence"... However, your question is rather like asking "My friend has a new pet.  Do I say 'It is a nice dog' or 'It is a nice cat'?" -- It depends if it is a cat or a dog, but both are possible in gramamr.  Just like that, it depends if you mean "will" or "would". Both are possible in grammar, but have different meanings.

Comment: We've said "I'd use....". "I'd use" or "I'll use" ? Please tell me the difference.

Comment: "I'd use" is the conditional "I'll use" is the future

Comment: In your previous comment you said "I'd use...". So your sense was conditional?

Comment: Yes.  "I would use that expression *if I was in that situation*".  Since I am not predicting the future, I don't say "I will use"